# How to avoid zombie process while working with named pipe?

Tags: docker, background-process, process-management, zombie-process

We normally do the writing job to a FIFO file in background using a control operator `&`. Something like below.

```
if [ ! -p "/tmp/mysqld.init" ]; then
    mkfifo /tmp/mysqld.init
fi

echo "something" > /tmp/mysqld.init &

exec mysqld --init-file=/tmp/mysqld.init
```

But when the fifo file is readout the `echo` process get a zombie process. How can it be avoided ?

**Note** This script is a docker entrypoint script and I don't have a proper zombie handler. Mysqld always takes the pid 1. Something like below.

```
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
    1     0 mysql    S     383m  19%   0   0% mysqld --init-file=/tmp/mysqld.init
   40     0 root     R     1532   0%   1   0% top
    7     1 root     Z        0   0%   0   0% [entrypoint.sh]
```

Probably I can use tini an init system for docker but without it how can it be achieved ? Double fork ?

Comment: You can not ups `exec`, but this will use up a process. Alternatively just let it happen. There is little cost in a zombie process. init is usually the reaper of lost children. As mysql is taking the role of init, this will not happen. It will probably be cheapest to just let it be a zombi. And no more than the cost of the un-used fifo that is left lying around.

Answer (score 2):

Working with Bourne Shell or Bash, you can use `trap` to close named-pipes. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
trap 'close_fifo; echo 1>&2 "!!! Unexpected signal termination."; exit 66' HUP TERM INT STOP

LOG_PATH="/tmp/acme.log"
touch "{$LOG_PATH}"

# Setup fifo and pipe input to log file with tee
FIFO=$(mktemp -u);
mkfifo $FIFO
tee -ia "{$LOG_PATH}" < $FIFO &

# Capture tee's process ID for the wait command.
TEE_PID=$!
# Redirect the rest of the stderr and stdout to our named pipe.
exec > $FIFO 2>&1

log() { echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')]: $*"; }

close_fifo() {
    # close the stderr and stdout file descriptors.
    exec 1>&- 2>&-

    # Wait for tee to finish since now that other end of the pipe has closed.
    [ -n $TEE_PID ] && wait $TEE_PID

    rm -f $FIFO
}

main() {
  // ---
  // Main procedure here...
}

main
close_fifo
```

This will trap any signals and close pipe on termination signals. Any stdout/err will be logged to a file using the named-pipe.

Fifo handling reference: https://superuser.com/a/86961/252171

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [surprisingly more complicated](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) than most people would expect.

The short answer is that you need to use init, or write a replacement for init that implements reaping and downstream signals propagation, or find a new way to pass data to mysqld, or find a way to live with it (which requires understanding and limiting your zombie creation rate).

zombie processes arise when their exit status is not collected (reaped) by the parent.  `exec` replaces the current process (a shell) with mysqld, which is not expecting to inherit child processes.

If you start mysqld in the background, and let the shell script remain to reap children, it also needs to handle propagating received signals to mysqld and waiting for them to respond.  Failing to do so will cause mysql to be un-gracefully terminated when the shell script exits.  This reaping and propagation is normally the job of `init`.

You can make the echo exit immediately by opening a handle for read, like this:

```
echo "something" > /tmp/fifo &
exec 3< /tmp/fifo
```

... but that creates a new problem: normally `echo` would close the fifo, and now it can't: it exits too soon.  That means mysql will block when reading it.  It's possible to do non-blocking reads and implement timeouts and all that, but we can assume mysql doesn't, because it probably expects `--init-file` to behave like a regular file.

The last option is to live with it.  If we're talking about 1 process or 100, that's fine.  But the process table is finite and each zombie consumes an entry in it.  If you don't manage the zombie count, and the process table fills, you can't create any new processes.

The blog post I linked has a lot of good detail and plugs a small init replacement, created by the author, to solve your exact problem.